# Is it possible to pre-populate fields in android CardIO

Tags: android

If my backend service declines a credit card acquired through the CardIOActivity, I would like to setup a new Intent to launch a new CardIOActivity that has the already input data pre-populated. I can't seem to find anything on this in the CardIO documentation. Does anyone know if this is possible or does anyone have a workaround? 
Thanks.

Additional info:

I start the CardIOActivity with the below intent currently, and fetch the result from onActivityResult(), but could find no flags or extras in the apk for pre-populated data.

```
Intent scanIntent = new Intent(this, CardIOActivity.class);
    scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_EXPIRY, true); // default: false
    scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_CVV, true); // default: false
    scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_POSTAL_CODE, true); // default: false
    scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_RESTRICT_POSTAL_CODE_TO_NUMERIC_ONLY, true);
    startActivityForResult(scanIntent, MY_SCAN_REQUEST_CODE);
```